# Utilizing Apple's new Force Click in Java

Tags: java, macos, click

Since Apple released the Force Click trackpad for some 2015 Macs, I've been wondering how to detect a force click. A force click is when you click once, then apply pressure until you click again (although the pressure in-between should be detectable). This is all handled with "haptic feedback" that makes you think you're clicking, when in fact you're not.

It's a pretty cool concept. But I'm wondering if there's something in Apple's Java API that lets you utilize it. Is there?

Comment: Not at the time of asking. You would need to delve into the world of native bindings to see if you could get it to work